# How to create a many to one relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, relationship, many-to-one

as the question states, how do I do create a many-to-one relationship in django models?

Basically, I have two models: Article and Comic, I want to have one Comment model which will have a relationship with both Article and Comic, but not both. 
So if a Comment object has a relationship with an Article object, then it wont have a relationship with a Comic object.

I am currently doing it the following way, which does not work:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    #other fields
class Comic(models.Model):
    #other fields
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    comic = models.ForeignKey(Comic)
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  I think there are a couple ways you could model this.

Using your current way you could enforce your uniqueness constraint in the application.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    comic = models.ForeignKey(Comic)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # assert that there is either comic OR article but not both
        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

with this way, what happens if you add another model that you want `Comment` to reference?? You will have to manually add the conditional for the new type in your save method and perform a migration.

Django provides GenericForeignKey field that would allow you to reference any model from `Comment`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

This would allow you to create a generic reference from `Comment` to either Article or Comic, and since it is only one field, would by default be mutually exclusive.  I find querying and using `GenericeForeignKey`s awkward; but they are still an option, that might work fine for your use case.

---

Another powerful option, (my favorite) could be to create a polymorphic model, which would also be mutually exclusive.

Each `Comment` could reference a generic Piece of `Content`, using model inheritance.  (I did not test the following, so it will probably not work as copied/pasted)

```
class Content(models.Model):
  objects = InheritanceManager()
  # shared content fields could be stored in this model

class Article(Content):
  # article specific fields

class Comic(Content):
  # comic specific fields

class Comment(models.Model):
  content = models.OneToOneField(Content)
```

This is a powerful way to model the relationship of `Comment` to any `Content`.  This DOES add additional query overhead, and should warrant an audit for your use case.

`InheritanceManager` is a utility provided by django-model-utils package, and is pretty lightweight.  I have used in in production environment and it is performant, as long as you understand the additional query overheard involved with modeling your data using it.  https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager

The query overhead is explained in the documentation.

If you think you will add additional `Content` subclasses in the future this could be a scalable way to model your relationship, and provides more flexibility in filtering then `GenericForeignKey`s.

Comment: Hmm, I knew this is a complicated problem. Thanks for the solutions, I will try them out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add another field to you Comment model. Like

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, null = True)
    comic = models.ForeignKey(Comic, null = True)
    assigned = models.BooleanField(initial=False)
```

Once a comment object is created, put either article or comic to point at another object and make assigned = True.